# If $A$ and $B$ are $2\times 2$ matrices and $AB=0$ then $A=0$ or $B=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is it true that if $A$ and $B$ are $2\times 2$ matrices and $AB=0$ then $A=0$ or $B=0$. Prove it, or prove the contrary.

I tried saying that if:
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad B= \begin{pmatrix}
        e & f  \\
        g & h  \\
        \end{pmatrix}.$$
The product will be 0. But, if $A$ is non zero, i tried doing something like this:

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        c & d  \\
        \end{pmatrix},\quad
    B = \begin{pmatrix}
        e & f  \\
        g & h  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\implies
AB = \begin{pmatrix}
        ae+bg & af+bh  \\
        ce+dg & cf+dh  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
is equal to \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
But then, how should i proceed? I don't know if these are the right steps to follow, i've tried searching, but i didn't find the right examples.

Comment: It's fine –– the way I understand, the point is to determine whether that statement is true (proof or counterex).

Answer (score 5):

For example you may try with
$$A=B=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Yes, i know the answer, didn't put it in the main text, but WHY is it that? How can i get that?

Comment: This is not the only case. You can find more examples playing with the coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f,g, h$. I gave one example because you said that "i didn't find the right examples."

Comment: @InfoB As a rule of thumb: if you have to find an example, the most effective method is a sort of "trial and error".  For most linear algebra examples, you should be able to construct an example containing mostly $0$s and some $1$s.

Comment: Yes, i know. But generally, i wanted a nice proof with only generic coefficients. What are the steps? Could i get further with my logic? @Omnomnomnom Hmmm, gonna note that, thank you!

Comment: What do you want to prove?  Do you mean you want to analyze all the ways in which this can happen, $A, B \ne 0$ but $AB = 0$?  Thinking directly in terms of coefficients is probably not the best way.  What you want is that  $\text{range}(B) \subseteq \text{kernel}(A)$.

Comment: @InfoB There is no "nice" proof that uses only generic coefficients.  One approach you might like, however, is to "guess" that both $A$ and $B$ have only zeros in the second row, and then work with the ensuing equations.

Comment: @InfoB One systematic approach that I favor is to begin by proving that $AB = 0$ if and only if the column space of $B$ is contained in the nullspace (kernel) of $A$.  In my mind, this yields the clearest justification for the example we arrived at.

Comment: Continuing my comment. So you should be thinking "structurally".  $A$ must have a one dimensional kernel.  All one dimensional subspaces are "the same"  so the kernel can be whatever you find convenient.  What I would find convenient is $\text{kernel}(A) = \text{span}\left[ \matrix{1\\ 0} \right ]$.

Comment: no, stay hard. Find at least one condition on $A,B$ such that $AB = 0$ for all $A,B$ satisfying this condition

Comment: Still continuing my comments, as Omnonmonmon (sp?)  said,  you want the column space of $B$ to be contained in the  kernal of $A$, which in turn is spanned by that one vector.  This pretty much describes everything that can happen.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your own calculation shows that if $a=g=1$ but all other variables vanish, then the product $AB$ will vanish, too. (There are other possibilities. Robert's solution is $b=f=1$.)

---

You may be interested to know that the failure of $AB=0$ to imply $A=0$ or $B=0$ when $A$ and $B$ are matrices means that "matrix algebras" have "zero divisors." This is one reason matrix algebra is harder than ordinary algebra.

The great master Halmos in *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*, for example:

> [...] the two nasty properties that the multiplication of linear transformations has [are] non-commutativity and the existence of divisors of zero.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "no".

If the first matrix has rank $1$ it annihilates a subspace of dimension $1$. All you need then is for a second matrix of rank $1$ to annihilate the subspace that the first preserves, and preserve the subspace that it annihilates (because once the first matrix annihilates it, it is gone).

You get a simple set of matrices if you choose a sensible basis (as others have done).

You are working in two dimensions here. I'm hoping that my comments will help you to find examples in more dimensions, and to build some intuition and understanding rather than just doing calculations.